# How to get index register from the instruction in IDA?

Tags: ida, idapro-sdk

I have the instruction:

```
add     edx, ds:dword_7BFC7A50[eax*4]
```

i.e.

```
add     edx, [eax*4+7BFC7A50h]
```

And I decode it via `decode_insn()`. Then I try to get the information about the second operand. I can get `7BFC7A50` from `insn_t.addr`, but I can't get any information about  `[eax*4]`. I mean I expect register number to be in `insn_t.ops[1].phrase`, but there's an invalid value. And for some reason `insn_t.ops[1].type` is `o_mem`, not `o_displ`.

Comment: If you want people to help you, make sure they can produce the issue you are experiencing on their local machine. In your cases it is quite relevant which disassembler you are using. Right now your question appears to be a question for the library developers and not really related to reverse engineering.

Comment: @mrexodia it probably could have been more explicit but the question *is* tagged “ida-sdk”